# serviceRemoved is not called while discovering the devices

Tags: android, jmdns

I am working on a project that needs to discover all the devices in the same wi-fi network. For implementing this I have used [Jmdns](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmdns/) library.

It is giving me the list of devices that are registered into the current network, but when the device gets unregistered it should call [serviceRemoved](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html) method of [ServiceListener](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html). However, it is not calling the `serviceRemoved` when the device is unregistered.

Here is my code.:

```
public class LanService {
    private static LanService instance = new LanService();
    private final String TYPE = "_sample._tcp.local.";
    private JmDNS jmdns = null;
    private ServiceInfo serviceInfo;
    private WifiManager.MulticastLock lock;
    private ServiceListener listener;

    public static LanService getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void startDiscovery() {
        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) AppBase.getAppContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Thread startDiscoveryThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (serviceInfo != null) {
                                stopScan();
                            }
                            setUp();
                        }
                    });
                    startDiscoveryThread.start();
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stopDiscovery() {
        Thread stopDiscoveryThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                stopScan();
            }
        });
        stopDiscoveryThread.start();

    }

    private void setUp() {
        try {
            WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) AppBase.getAppContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            if (!wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {
                wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
            }

            // get the device ip address
            final InetAddress deviceIpAddress = getLocalIpAddress();
            if (deviceIpAddress != null) {
                lock = wifi.createMulticastLock(getClass().getName());
                lock.setReferenceCounted(true);
                lock.acquire();
                jmdns = JmDNS.create(deviceIpAddress);

                serviceInfo = ServiceInfo.create(TYPE, Build.MODEL, 3129, "plain test service from android");
                jmdns.registerService(serviceInfo);

                jmdns.addServiceListener(TYPE, listener = new ServiceListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void serviceResolved(ServiceEvent ev) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Service Resolved : " + ev.getInfo().getQualifiedName() + " ipAddr : " + ev.getInfo().getInetAddresses()[0]);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void serviceRemoved(ServiceEvent ev) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Service Removed : " + ev.getInfo().getQualifiedName() + " ipAddr : " + ev.getInfo().getInetAddresses()[0]);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void serviceAdded(ServiceEvent ev) {
                        try {
                            // Required to force serviceResolved to be called again (after the first search)
                            Log.d(TAG, "Service Added : " + ev.getInfo().getQualifiedName());
                            jmdns.requestServiceInfo(ev.getType(), ev.getName(), 1000);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Started ZeroConf probe....");
    }

    private void stopScan() {
        try {
            if (jmdns != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Stopping ZeroConf probe....");
                jmdns.removeServiceListener(TYPE, listener);
                jmdns.unregisterService(serviceInfo);
                jmdns.unregisterAllServices();
                jmdns.close();
                jmdns = null;
            }
            if (lock != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Releasing Mutlicast Lock...");
                if (lock.isHeld())
                    lock.release();
                lock = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Why is `serviceRemoved` not getting invoked when the device is unregistered from the network?  Any suggestions are appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

Why do you open a thread inside the runnable of the handler? The Handler runs the runnable on a separate thread. What you do is:

-The handler runs the runnable on a thread and you open another thread and do your stuff. Maybe that is your problem.

Instead of this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Thread startDiscoveryThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (serviceInfo != null) {
                                stopScan();
                            }
                            setUp();
                        }
                    });
                    startDiscoveryThread.start();
                }
            }, 2000);
```

Try this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                            if (serviceInfo != null) {
                                stopScan();
                            }
                       setUp();
                    }

            }, 2000);
```

Comment: Here my problem is not about scanning,
serviceRemoved is not getting called

Comment: Yes. And I believe it is because you do not handle your handler and your threads properly.